# NgRx store problem: Wrong types of params passing at reduecer function

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I would like to make a simple reducer work.
I copied a code from: [coursetro.com][1] but something went wrong when I finished updating app.module.ts. it gaved me an error message

> Type '(state: Tutorial[] | undefined, action: Actions) => Tutorial[]' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducer<Tutorial[], Action>'.
> Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
> Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'Actions'.
> Property 'payload' is missing in type 'Action' but required in type 'RemoveTutorial'.

I assumed, from the error message, that I somehow try to pass in param 2, type Action to a function that accepts type Actions.
I know that I pass type TutorialActions.Actions that it should be equal to type Action. But Maybe I should use casting it order to that to work because it it typed "TutorialActions.Actions" and not "Action" ?

I would like to make this solution simple as possible.
[1]: https://coursetro.com/posts/code/151/Angular-Ngrx-Store-Tutorial---Learn-Angular-State-Management

Some Code:
reducer.ts

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store'
import { Tutorial } from './../models/tutorial.model'
import * as TutorialActions from './../actions/tutorial.actions'


const initialState: Tutorial = {
name: 'Initial Tutorial',
url: 'http://google.com'
}

 export function reducer(state: Tutorial[] = [initialState], action: TutorialActions.Actions) 
{


switch(action.type) {
    case TutorialActions.ADD_TUTORIAL:
        return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

actions:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store'
import { Tutorial } from '../models/tutorial.model'

export const ADD_TUTORIAL       = '[TUTORIAL] Add'
export const REMOVE_TUTORIAL    = '[TUTORIAL] Remove'

export class AddTutorial implements Action {
    readonly type = ADD_TUTORIAL

    constructor(public payload: Tutorial) {}
}


export class RemoveTutorial implements Action {
    readonly type = REMOVE_TUTORIAL

    constructor(public payload: number) {}
}

export type Actions = AddTutorial | RemoveTutorial
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Tutorial } from './../models/tutorial.model';
import { AppState } from './../app.state';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-read',
  templateUrl: './read.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./read.component.scss']
})
export class ReadComponent implements OnInit {


  tutorials: Observable<Tutorial[]>;


  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.tutorials = store.select('tutorial');
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Actions:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Tutorial } from '../models/tutorial.model'

export const addTutorial = createAction('[TUTORIAL] Add', props<{payload: Tutorial}>());
export const removeTutorial = createAction('[TUTORIAL] Remove', props<{id: number}>());
```

Reducer:

```
import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Tutorial } from './../models/tutorial.model'
import * as tutorialActions from './../actions/tutorial.actions'

export const initialState: Tutorial[] = [];

const _tutorialsReducer = createReducer(initialState,
  on(tutorialActions.addTutorial, (state, {payload}) => [...state, ...payload]),
  on(tutorialActions.removeTutorial, (state, {id}) => {
    return state.filter(t => t.id != id);
  })
);

export function tutorialsReducer(state: any, action: Action) {
  return _tutorialsReducer(state, action);
}
```

AppModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
...

// NgRx
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ tutorials: tutorialsReducer }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: ristofer, I am sorry but this solution is changing my whole code and it wouldn't allow me to proceed through the tutorial. I don't think its a good idea to do that. Thanks for your efforts –

Comment: What version of Angular you are using? The project from the tutorial uses Angular v5 and the last version is 12